# VLSM Error on Cisco Distribution Switch

Tags: cisco, switch, router, subnet, networking

I have created 3 VLANS which should not overlap but somehow are giving me overlapping problems. Any reasons why? Is the switch buggy?

VLAN 10 10.1.1.0/28
255.255.255.240 Usable:10.1.1.0 to 10.1.1.15

VLAN 20 10.1.1.16/29
255.255.255.248 Usable:10.1.1.16 to 10.1.1.23

VLAN 30 10.1.1.24/28
255.255.255.240 Usable: 10.1.1.24 to 10.1.1.39

```
Switch(config-if)#int vlan10
Switch(config-if)#ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.240
Switch(config-if)#int vlan 20
Switch(config-if)#ip address 10.1.1.17 255.255.255.248
Switch(config-if)#int vlan 30
Switch(config-if)#ip address 10.1.1.25 255.255.255.240
% 10.1.1.16 overlaps with Vlan20
```

Comment: See [the excellent answers to this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers) for how to calculate subnets and prefixes. Also, "VLSM" is an obsolete term from the classful networking era more than thirty years ago - it's called CIDR since.

Answer (score 2):

The subnet that 10.1.1.25/28 belongs to is 10.1.1.16/28, which overlaps with VLAN 20.  It doesn't magically start at .24 just because you want it to.

Comment: I will need to use VLSM subnetting chart for this, correct?

Comment: See the comment above to your question and follow that link.  You can use a chart or calculator -- up to you.